# GA4 E-commerce purchases can only show some of the item revenue but not all

Tags: google-tag-manager, google-analytics-4

I have cross-checked all the datalayer and GTM configuration and everything seems fine. All the transaction values are able to be captured in "Engagement > Conversions" report but not in "Monetization > E-commerce purchases" report

[Screenshot of GA4 E-commerce purchases report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iONVD.png)

Required parameter i.e. Transaction id and Currency are able to capture

Any ideas what might be wrong? Thanks a lot!